# How to execute Blackberry OS 6 app in Blackberry 10 OS

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-10, blackberry-webworks

I developed one application in Blackberry OS 6.I deployed that app in to Blackberry world successfully.But it is not working in Blackberry OS 10.I am getting following error:

**Unsupported for this device**

Please help me how to run application in OS 10.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OS10 is a completely different system.  It no longer supports the BB6/7 Java environment. You will need to port your app to one of the new supported platforms:

http://developer.blackberry.com/develop/platform_choice/index.html

- Cascades (c++ & qml)
- Webworks
- Android
- Adobe Air

Answer (score 0):

With **WebWorks** it is possible to run your application in both BlackBerry 6 and BlackBerry 10, you may need to make some changes to your code, but it is certainly possible and there are plenty of resources available.

You can start from [here](http://developer.blackberry.com/html5/documentation/what_is_a_webworks_app_1845471_11.html).

Specifically BlackBerry states:

> Your BlackBerry WebWorks app can be targeted to run on a variety of
> BlackBerry device models or ported to a different OS, such as iOS or
> Android.
>
> Developing your app with BlackBerry WebWorks gives you the flexibility
> to target users of the latest BlackBerry devices and those who are
> using older models. Depending on the OS you want to target, versions
> of the BlackBerry WebWorks SDK available for:
>
> - BlackBerry 10
> - BlackBerry PlayBook
> - BlackBerry 7 and earlier

See [here](http://developer.blackberry.com/html5/documentation/creating_hello_world.html) for a tutorial on creating an application which is able to work on old and new BB devices (Simple Hello World application).

A good article to look at can be found [here](http://developer.blackberry.com/html5/documentation/webworks_process_overview.html), which explains some of the fundamentals and differences with webworks.

Comment: sadly all of your 'here' are 404s :(