# Installing .cod file to blackberry q5

Tags: blackberry, nginx, blackberry-10, javaloader

I have a .cod file that I want to install to my blackberry. When I try javaloader
"javaloader -u load *.cod" I get the following error.

Connecting to device...debug: HRESULT error during Open: 80040154
Error: unable to open port

Additionally, I have tried hosting the .cod and .jad file on the nginx server and then accessing it from my device webbrowser.

Before I start the nginx webserver I put the following in the mime.type file in nginx.

application/vnd.rim.cod cod;
text/vnd.sun.j2me.app-descriptor jad;

However when I try to access the .jad file from my blackberry web browser it just opens up the .jad file in the browser and when I try to install the .cod file, it installs it on the device but when i click on it my blackberry says unable to install.

My blackberry model is q5.

Can anyone help me with installing the .cod file on my blackberry?

Thanks,

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to execute Blackberry OS 6 app in Blackberry 10 OS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17590976/how-to-execute-blackberry-os-6-app-in-blackberry-10-os)

Answer (score 0):

You can't.  cod files work on BBOS, and are not supported by BB10.  What you are attempting to do is a little like trying to install a Linux application on a Windows PC.